# quantity and price not increasing

Tags: android, listview

I have created a Listview in which i want to increase and decrease quantity and price on click of +.The problem is that when I click on + and - its not increasing or decreasing.Can anyone give me correct code plz.Thanks for ur help in advance.
Here is my code-

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    Button show;
    ListView list_item;
    ArrayList<Items> itemsArrayList;

    SearchView searchview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list_item = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdetails);

        searchview = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnview);
        itemsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemsArrayList.add(new Items(1, "Book", 20, 0, 0));
        itemsArrayList.add(new Items(2, "Pen", 25, 0, 0));
        itemsArrayList.add(new Items(3, "Scale", 10, 0, 0));
        itemsArrayList.add(new Items(4, "Eraser", 5, 0, 0));

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Trial.class);
                intent.putExtra("data", itemsArrayList);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Custom c = new Custom(this,itemsArrayList);
        list_item.setAdapter(c);
        list_item.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();
    }

    public void setupSearchView() {
        searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchview.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
            list_item.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            list_item.setFilterText(s);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Custom.java**

```
public class Custom extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
    Activity a;
    ArrayList<Items> itemsArrayList;
    ArrayList<Items> filtered;

    public Custom(Activity a, ArrayList<Items> itemsArrayList) {
        this.a = a;
        this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return itemsArrayList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<Items> data = new ArrayList<Items>();
                if (filtered == null)
                    filtered = itemsArrayList;
                if (filtered != null && filtered.size() > 0) {
                    for (final Items g : filtered) {
                        if (g.getItemname().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(charSequence.toString()))
                            data.add(g);
                    }
                    results.values = data;
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                itemsArrayList = (ArrayList<Items>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class Holder{
        TextView sr, item, qty, price, pl, min, rate;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        LayoutInflater li = a.getLayoutInflater();
        final View view1 = li.inflate(R.layout.customlist, viewGroup, false);
        holder.sr = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.s_no);
        holder.item = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.i_name);
        holder.qty = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        holder.price = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.pr);
        holder.rate = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.frate);
        holder.pl=(TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.pl);
        holder.min=(TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.min);
        final Items model = itemsArrayList.get(position);

        holder.sr.setText(String.valueOf(itemsArrayList.get(position).getSrno()));
        holder.item.setText(String.valueOf(itemsArrayList.get(position).getItemname()));
        holder.rate.setText(String.valueOf(itemsArrayList.get(position).getFixedrate()));
        holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(itemsArrayList.get(position).getQuantity()));
        holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(itemsArrayList.get(position).getRate()));

        holder.pl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int temp = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(model.getQuantity())) + 1;
                int price1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(model.getFixedrate())) * temp;
                holder.qty.setText(temp + " ");
                holder.price.setText(price1 + " ");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.min.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int temp = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(model.getQuantity())) - 1;
                int price1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(model.getFixedrate())) * temp;
                if (temp > 0) {
                    int tempPrice = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(model.getFixedrate())) * temp;
                    holder.qty.setText(temp + " ");
                    holder.price.setText(price1 + " ");
                } else {
                    int tempPrice = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(model.getFixedrate())) * 0;
                    holder.qty.setText(temp + " ");
                    holder.price.setText(price1 + " ");
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return view1;
    }
}
```

**Items.java**

```
public class Items implements Serializable {
    int srno, fixedrate, quantity, rate;
    String itemname;

    public Items(int srno, String itemname, int fixedrate, int quantity, int rate) {
        this.srno = srno;
        this.itemname = itemname;
        this.fixedrate = fixedrate;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public int getSrno() {
        return srno;
    }

    public void setSrno(int srno) {
        this.srno = srno;
    }

    public String getItemname() {
        return itemname;
    }

    public void setItemname(String itemname) {
        this.itemname = itemname;
    }

    public int getFixedrate() {
        return fixedrate;
    }

    public void setFixedrate(int fixedrate) {
        this.fixedrate = fixedrate;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(int rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:queryHint="Search "
    >
</SearchView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sr_no"
    >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/srno"
            android:layout_below="@+id/breakfast"
            android:text="ITEM NAME"
            android:id="@+id/itemname"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/fixrate"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_name">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/srno"
            android:layout_below="@+id/breakfast"
            android:text="RATE"
            android:id="@+id/fixratee"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/qtity"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fixrate"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemname"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lunch"
            android:text="QTY"
            android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qtity"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/count"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_below="@+id/snacks"
            android:text="PRICE"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sr_no"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/breakfast"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="SR.NO"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/srno"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/listdetails"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </ListView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnview"
        android:text="View"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listdetails"
        android:clickable="true">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**customlist.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/s_no"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/frate"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/i_name"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/pl"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qty"
        android:background="@drawable/plus1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/qty"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/frate"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/min"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/pl"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/qty"
        android:background="@drawable/minus1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/pr"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/min"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pl"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pl" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/i_name"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/s_no"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/s_no"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/s_no"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/s_no" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use textwatcher

Comment: i want code for increment and decrement only .Maybe my code of holder.pl.setOnclickListener and holder.min.setOnclickListener is having some issue. See that in Custom.java page

Comment: Implement with one integer variable which will be incremented when click on + and decremented when click on -

Comment: I have used one integer only temp for quantity and price1 for price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try it:**

```
    holder.pl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            model.setQuantity(model.getQuantity() + 1);
            model.setRate(model.getQuantity() * model.getFixedrate());
            holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(model.getQuantity()));
            holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(model.getRate()));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });



    holder.min.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (model.getQuantity() > 0) {
                model.setQuantity(model.getQuantity() - 1);
                model.setRate(model.getQuantity() * model.getFixedrate());
                holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(model.getQuantity()));
                holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(model.getRate()));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have one more problem.Will give that problem link here after I post it.I wont be able to post new question for 90 mins.So check it later plz ok.

Comment: Sure I will try :)

Comment: Yes Thanks for ur help:). Check it after 2hrs for another problem.Till then i will try on my own.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370771/to-pass-only-incremented-value-to-listview-on-nextpage?noredirect=1#comment73803399_43370771   check this link plz and try it.Its the problem I was telling about.

Answer (score 0):

The model is not updated with the new incremented/decremented value.

```
holder.pl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    model.setQuantity(model.getQuantity() + 1)
    holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(model.getQuantity()));
    holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(model.getQuantity() * 
    model.getFixedrate()));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it.

```
holder.pl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                model.setQuantity(model.getQuantity() + 1);
                model.setRate(model.getQuantity()*model.getFixedrate());
                holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(model.getQuantity()));
                holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(model.getRate()));
                notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
```