# To pass only incremented value to listview on nextpage

Tags: android, listview

I am able to send data on listview in nextpage.But problem is that items with quantity 0 is also passed.I want to show items whose quantity is incremented and not all items present in listview.Here is my code-

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    Button show;
    ListView list_item;
    ArrayList<Items> itemsArrayList;
   SearchView searchview;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list_item = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdetails);

        searchview=(SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnview);
        itemsArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        itemsArrayList.add(new Items(1,"Book",20,0,0));
        itemsArrayList.add(new Items(2,"Pen",25,0,0));
        itemsArrayList.add(new Items(3,"Scale",10,0,0));
        itemsArrayList.add(new Items(4,"Eraser",5,0,0));

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Trial.class);
                intent.putExtra("data", itemsArrayList);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        Custom c = new Custom(this,itemsArrayList);
        list_item.setAdapter(c);
        list_item.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();

    }

   public void setupSearchView()
    {

        searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        searchview.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
            list_item.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            list_item.setFilterText(s);
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

**Custom.java**

```
public class Custom extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
    Activity a;
    ArrayList<Items> itemsArrayList;
    ArrayList<Items> filtered;




    public Custom(Activity a, ArrayList<Items> itemsArrayList) {
        this.a = a;
        this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return itemsArrayList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<Items> data=new ArrayList<Items>();
                if (filtered==null)
                    filtered=itemsArrayList;
                if (filtered != null && filtered.size() > 0) {
                    for (final Items g : filtered) {
                        if (g.getItemname().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(charSequence.toString()))
                            data.add(g);
                    }
                    results.values=data;
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                itemsArrayList=(ArrayList<Items>)filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class Holder{
        TextView sr,item,qty,price,pl,min,rate;


    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final Holder holder=new Holder();
        LayoutInflater li=a.getLayoutInflater();
        final View view1=li.inflate(R.layout.customlist,viewGroup,false);
        holder.sr=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.s_no);
        holder.item=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.i_name);
        holder.qty=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        holder.price=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.pr);
        holder.rate=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.frate);
        holder.pl=(TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.pl);
        holder.min=(TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.min);
        final Items model = itemsArrayList.get(position);

        holder.sr.setText(String.valueOf(itemsArrayList.get(position).getSrno()));
        holder.item.setText(String.valueOf(itemsArrayList.get(position).getItemname()));
        holder.rate.setText(String .valueOf(itemsArrayList.get(position).getFixedrate()));
        holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(itemsArrayList.get(position).getQuantity()));
        holder.price.setText(String .valueOf(itemsArrayList.get(position).getRate()));

        holder.pl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                model.setQuantity(model.getQuantity() + 1);
                model.setRate(model.getQuantity()*model.getFixedrate());
                holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(model.getQuantity()));
                holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(model.getRate()));
                notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });


        holder.min.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(model.getQuantity()>0) {
                    model.setQuantity(model.getQuantity() - 1);
                    model.setRate(model.getQuantity() * model.getFixedrate());
                    holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(model.getQuantity()));
                    holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(model.getRate()));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
        return view1;
    }


}
```

**Items.java**

```
public class Items implements Serializable {
    int srno,fixedrate,quantity,rate;
    String itemname;

    public Items(int srno, String itemname, int fixedrate, int quantity, int rate) {
        this.srno = srno;
        this.itemname = itemname;
        this.fixedrate = fixedrate;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public int getSrno() {
        return srno;
    }

    public void setSrno(int srno) {
        this.srno = srno;
    }

    public String getItemname() {
        return itemname;
    }

    public void setItemname(String itemname) {
        this.itemname = itemname;
    }

    public int getFixedrate() {
        return fixedrate;
    }

    public void setFixedrate(int fixedrate) {
        this.fixedrate = fixedrate;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(int rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
}
```

**Custom_Trial.java**

```
public class Custom_Trial extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity a;
    private ArrayList<Items> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public Custom_Trial(Activity a, ArrayList<Items> data) {
        this.a = a;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView sr, it, qty, amt;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        LayoutInflater li = a.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = li.inflate(R.layout.customtrial, parent, false);
        holder.sr = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.head1);
        holder.it = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.head2);
        holder.qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.head3);
        holder.amt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.head4);



        Items m = data.get(position);



            holder.sr.setText(String.valueOf(m.getSrno()));
            holder.it.setText(m.getItemname());
            holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(m.getQuantity()));
            holder.amt.setText(String.valueOf(m.getRate()));




        return view;
    }

}
```

**Trial.java**

```
public class Trial extends Activity{
    ListView listnew;
    private ArrayList<Items> data = new ArrayList<>();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.trial);

        listnew = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newlist);

        data.addAll((ArrayList<Items>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data"));


        Custom_Trial ct = new Custom_Trial(this,data);
        listnew.setAdapter(ct);

    }



}
```

Comment: You can pass quantity only if it is `>0`.

Comment: As i am sending data from Items class whole data is going.Cant understand where to put that condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you passing original list. You're updating values inside adapter and passing not updated list fromadapter, but original. Write method inside adapter to return your updated list.

**Inside Custom.java adapter:**

```
public ArrayList<Items> getItems(){
    ArrayList<Items> quantityArrayList;
    Items item;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsArrayList.size(); i++){
        item =  itemsArrayList.get(i);
        if (item.getQuantity() > 0)
        quantityArrayList.add(item);
    }

    return quantityArrayList;
}
```

**And inside MainActivity onCreate() should look like this. After clicking show button you're going to get Items from Custom Adapter whose quantity >0.**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list_item = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdetails);

    searchview=(SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnview);
    itemsArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    itemsArrayList.add(new Items(1,"Book",20,0,0));
    itemsArrayList.add(new Items(2,"Pen",25,0,0));
    itemsArrayList.add(new Items(3,"Scale",10,0,0));
    itemsArrayList.add(new Items(4,"Eraser",5,0,0));

    Custom c = new Custom(this,itemsArrayList);
    list_item.setAdapter(c);
    list_item.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    setupSearchView();

    show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Trial.class);
            List<Items> quantityList = c.getItems();
            intent.putExtra("data", quantityList);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: In which page i should do this?